# Motive behind strict mode syntax error when deleting an unqualified identifier?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I'm having trouble understanding why, in strict mode, a syntax error occurs when `delete` is used on an unqualified identifier.

In most cases, it makes sense... if you are declaring variables in the usual way with the `var` keyword, and then trying to use `delete` on them, in non-strict mode it would silently fail, so it makes sense for strict mode to fail with an error in those cases.

However, there are cases where you *can't* delete identifiers that *are* qualified:

```
(function() {

  // "use strict";

  var obj = Object.create({}, { bloop: { configurable: false } });

  delete obj.bloop; // throws TypeError in strict mode, silently fails in non-strict.

  console.log('bloop' in obj); // true

}());
```

Strict mode must do a runtime check here, because a TypeError is thrown when this is encountered. There are also cases where you *can* successfully delete unqualified identifiers in non-strict mode...

```
// "use strict";

window.bar = 6;

console.log(typeof bar); // number

delete bar; // works in non-strict, syntax error in strict!

console.log(typeof bar); // undefined
```

In fact, to my understanding, whether or not you can delete things (in non-strict mode) depends on the internal `[[Configurable]]` property, and has nothing to do with qualified identifiers. As far as I can tell, there is no way in strict mode to delete non-global variables that (as properties of the local VO) *are* configurable:

```
(function() {

  // "use strict";

  eval('var foo = 5;');

  console.log(typeof foo); // number

  delete foo; // works in non-strict, SyntaxError in strict.

  console.log(typeof foo); // undefined

}());
```

So, my question is, what's the point of throwing a SyntaxError when using `delete` on an unqualified identifier, when the TypeError would throw anyway if the property is not configurable? This seems like an unnecessary restriction, and in some cases there doesn't seem to be any workaround other than not using strict mode (third example). Can anyone explain the motivation behind this decision?

---

Update: I just realized that I was overlooking the fact that direct `eval` calls have their own scope in strict mode, instead of the calling function's scope, so in the third example `foo` would not be defined under strict mode. Anyway, the runtime check would still catch this, but it raises a side question: Is there no way to have configurable local variables in strict mode, as we do with `eval`'d variable declarations in non-strict? AFAIK that was one of the few legitimate uses of `eval`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "(un)qualified identifier"? I can't find that term in the specs.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 an identifier with no dots in it. :)

Comment: @Pumbaa80 `(function(){"use strict"; var foo; delete foo;}())` ... chromium: `SyntaxError: Delete of an unqualified identifier in strict mode.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are talking about [Section 11.4.1, paragraph 5.a.](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.1) of the specs:

> 5. Else, ref is a Reference to an Environment Record binding, so
>         a. If IsStrictReference(ref) is true, throw a SyntaxError exception.
>         b. Let bindings be GetBase(ref).
>         c. Return the result of calling the DeleteBinding concrete method of bindings, providing GetReferencedName(ref) as the argument.

What you called "unqualified identifiers" is officially named "Environment Record binding".

Now, to your question. Why throw a SyntaxError when 5.c. would fail anyway? I think you answered it yourself!

> Strict mode must do a **runtime check** here, because a TypeError is thrown **when this is encountered**.

That's right. But it's always better to fail fast. So, when there is a chance of detecting a SyntaxError (at **parse time**), that opportunity should be taken.

Why? It saves you the trouble of fixing your app if an error occurs. Think about IDEs that may show you the error right away, as opposed to hours of debugging.
Also, such restrictions may be advantageous for optimized JIT compilers.

Comment: Thanks for digging up that spec reference. It makes sense to think of it as a debugging aide or JIT optimizer. If it gets used like that, I guess it's worth the tradeoff of not being able to delete things you'd be able to otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to delete object in strict mode. You have to explicitly mention about the property access. Also note that, how you call the function is important. If `new` operator isn't used `this` is undefined under `use strict`, and you cant use the below method.
Example:

```
'use strict'
function func(){
  var self = this;
  self.obj = {};
  self.obj.x = 'y'

  console.log(self.obj);
  delete self.obj // works
  // delete obj // doesn't work
  console.log(self.obj);
}

var f = new func();
```

For deleting object outside of the function(closure), you will have to call like

```
// same code as above
delete f.obj
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of your example is. Why are we making an alias for `this`? And `delete obj` wouldn't work in non-strict either unless you didn't use `new`, but that doesn't look like the intended purpose of the code. Unless I'm reading it wrong, this kind of seems like a rehashing of my question. +1 anyway for the effort and because I'm probably just missing your point ;)

Comment: well, aliasing this is my style you can say. The reason I use that is `this` will not be available under anonymous functions, where as a variable `var self` will be available
Oh, about `delete obj` not work under `new` -- I din't know ( I am relatively new to JS)
Oh, I read the question wrong, never mind.