# What is a direct reference?

Tags: javascript, reference, theory

One of the strict mode rules ([Annex C](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-C)) states:

> When a `delete` operator occurs within strict mode code, a **SyntaxError** is thrown if its *UnaryExpression* is a direct reference to a variable, function argument, or function name.

So in this code:

```
delete x
```

`x` is a reference. (I know this because ["the result of evaluating an Identifier is always a value of type Reference"](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.2)). But is it a *direct* reference?

And, are there other kinds of references? Indirect references? (If not, what's the point of using the word "direct" at all?)

Comment: "Direct reference" just means a reference without dots or subscript notation. V8 calls it an "unqualified identifier."

Comment: @GGG Yes, that sounds very reasonable. Also, when `delete x`, Firefox throws *"SyntaxError: applying the 'delete' operator to an unqualified name is deprecated"*, which confirms your statement.

Comment: What I'd like to know now is what problem that fixed. I didn't even know you could delete non-properties prior to strict mode. I suppose it could cause some confusion where a long chain of references was concerned if you killed the thing all the references point at.

Comment: @ErikReppen `delete` is designed to delete properties. Trying to delete variables, and other kinds of direct references, is improper usage. By default, JavaScript ignores this improper usage, and merely returns `false`. Strict mode, however, throws. When a program uses an operator (like `delete`) improperly, the program should throw - so, strict mode does the right thing. Ideally, this should be the default behavior, but that would break some existing (legacy) programs. That's why this behavior was made opt-in via strict mode.

Comment: Ah, okay. And in Chrome at least you can delete global vars in non-strict.

Comment: @ErikReppen, I asked that once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643587/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are different kinds of `References` ([EcmaScript §8.7](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7)). The member operators ([EcmaScript §11.2.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1)) for example do result in references whose *base value* is the value of the `baseReference`, which I'd call "not direct". A "direct reference" would be an identifier reference ([EcmaScript §10.2.2.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.2.1), where the base value is an Environment Record.

Comment: I meant, other kind in regard to a "direct reference". (So, given a direct reference, are there other kinds of references that are not direct references?) That chapter does not mention this term.

Comment: Yea, could be. A direct reference would be a reference resolved **solely** via [identifier resolution](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3.1), whereas an indirect reference would be a property reference (e.g. `obj.prop`), which is resolved in **two** steps: First, identifier resolution is performed on the name `"obj"`, which resolves in a reference to the object, and then, a **new** reference is forged, which base-value is the object-reference, and which name is `"prop"`. Yea, I think that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that's not defined as a property if I understand it correctly.

These should throw errors or fail in a console:

```
(function(){ 'use strict'; var x = '2'; delete x; })();
(function(){ 'use strict'; delete arguments[0]; })('2');
```

Comment: Even when you define a global variable, it will still throw if you refer to it solely by name. For instance: `this.x = true;` (in global code, so `this` is the global object), now `delete x` throws, but `delete this.x` doesn't. So, what matters is how you refer to it in the delete-expression, not weather it's a global property or not.

Comment: Yeah I thought I  had strict mode in a spot where I didn't when testing in console. Fixed.