# How does typeof circumvent the ReferenceError when supplied an undeclared variable identifier?

Tags: javascript

```
foo; // ReferenceError: foo is not defined

typeof(foo); // undefined
```

How does `typeof` circumvent the `ReferenceError` when supplied an undeclared variable identifier? Is this just JavaScript interpreter "magic" or can it be explained in terms of user-land concepts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this cannot be explained in user-land concepts - it's "magic" if you want.

EcmaScript uses the [*Reference* specification type](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7) to explain cases like this. These references are used to describe the semantics of assignments, [method calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25609986/1048572), [`eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12610333/1048572) and many more. Typically, the [GetValue algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) is called on them to dereference them (e.g. in the evaluation of your expression statement), and this does throw the `ReferenceError` when the reference is not resolvable.

The [`typeof` operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3) in contrast does not just do GetValue, but has a special case to handle these undeclared-variable references:

> 2. If `Type(val)` is *Reference*, then
>
>    a. If [`IsUnresolvableReference(val)`](http://es5.github.io/#IsUnresolvableReference) is `true`, return `"undefined"`.