# What is `base value` of `reference` in ECMAScript(ECMA-262 5.1)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I've been trying to understand how `this` value is set in javascript, and found ECMAScript Language Specification pretty much helpful. I was reading [section 8.7](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7) `reference specification type` and found that reference in ECMAScript is made of 3 component, `base value`, `referenced name`, `strict reference flag`to understand [section 11.2.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.3).

I can assume what are `referenced name` and `strict reference flag` from their name, but i don't understand what is the `base value`. The document says that `base value` is either `undefined`, `String`, `Boolean`, `Number` and `Object`, but it does not say how it is set and what it is. I am guessing it is something similar to context object. Could anyone explain?

Comment: like @shashank points out, `this` inherits the `typeof` from whatever object it is referencing. i believe all variables in JS are of `Prototype Object`

Comment: @Shashank: The value of `this` is not transformed, it's not a special object or type. `this` is special because the value is directly referenced from the execution context, not the corresponding environment record. The value however is just like any other value. The question doesn't actually have to do anything with `this`.

Comment: http://perfectionkills.com/know-thy-reference/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the *base value* is the context in which the referenced name lives.

For an object property, this would be the object (see [§8.12 Object internal methods](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12) for setter/getter operations). For a variable, this would be the variable environment ([§10.2.1 Environment records](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.1)). For an unresolvable reference (the things that throw reference errors [except when supplied to `typeof`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29155472/1048572)), this would be `undefined`.

> it does not say how it is set

`Reference` values are only constructed by very few operations:

- [identifier reference expressions](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.2), that [resolve the identifier](http://es5.github.io/#x10.3.1) in the [current lexical environment](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.2.1) (or one of its parents)
- [property accessor expressions](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1), i.e. the `.…` and `[…]`  operators
- function calls to host functions are permitted to return them, [but such don't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13124417/1048572).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am kinda starting to understand it. I also read [Section 10.4.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3), it says if it is either `null` or `undefined`, `this` value is set to global object. So one more question, is there any case that  `base value` is `null`?

Comment: Notice that the `thisBinding` has nothing to do with reference values. The `thisArg` is just a value supplied by the caller - never `null` in case of a method invocation indeed, but you could use [`.call(null)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4) as well. No, a reference is never constructed with `null` as the *base value*. `null.x` and `undefined.x` [do throw immediately](http://es5.github.io/#x9.10), and identifiers references have only `undefined` passed explicitly.

Comment: When is the base value a `Boolean`, `Number`, or `String` ?

Comment: @Taurus When you access a property on a primitive value

Comment: @Bergi Isn't it boxed when you do that (so it is just like you are accessing it on an object) ? BTW does this section in the spec confirm that everything in JS is a reference (and that everything is by reference and not by value) ?

Comment: @Taurus No, it does get boxed only when the reference is evaluated (`GetValue`), not when the reference is constructed. And No, this has nothing to do with reference-values vs primitive-values, notice that all references are evaluated to their values before a call.

Comment: If Type(V) is not Reference, return V. When will Type(V) will not be a reference. Is it in case of literals ??

Comment: @Harish_N Where are you citing this from? (No, `V` typically can be any value, not necessarily a primitive one or one constructed by a literal)

Comment: @Harish_N The `GetValue()` algorithm is called throughout the entire spec, and in most cases not with a reference.