# What is the difference between the specification types Environment Record (Lexical Environment) and Reference, in ECMAScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

Reading the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0), it seems both an [Environment Record](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-environment-records) (a component of a [Lexical Environment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-lexical-environments)), and a [Reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-reference-specification-type) is used to determine what variable / function an `Identifier` is bound to. In other words, finding the actual value represented by the Identifier.

I noticed that a `Reference`'s `Base value` component can contain an `Environment Record`:

> The base value component is either undefined, an Object, a Boolean, a
>   String, a Symbol, a Number, or an Environment Record.

But, it is not clear to me when one would use a `Reference` instead of the execution context just reading an `Environment Record` straight out of the current `Lexical Environment` (as given by the `running execution context`'s `LexicalEnvironment` component).

---

**EDIT:**

After accepting @Bergi 's answer, I wanted to add a couple of things I had not understood, in case it will help future readers:

1. Identifier lookups in ECMAScript always returns a `Reference` type

   - To resolve a variable/function name, we start at [8.3.2 ResolveBinding](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-resolvethisbinding)
   - You will see that the `running execution context`'s `LexicalEnvironment` (its Environment Record) is first checked
   - If no match is found, the Lexical Environment chain is followed outwards until a match (or not) is found
   - The chain ends at the `global environment`, which has an outer environment of `null`
   - Once a match is found, a `Reference` type is returned, which has its `base value` set to the value of the name in the Environment Record that matched
   - If no match is found, a `Reference` with a `base value` of `undefined` is returned
   - Thus, an identifier lookup *always* entails Environment Records being checked and a `Reference` type returned at the end
2. `Reference`'s `GetValue` is *only* ever done after evaluation of an `Expression`

   - `GetValue(ref)` is used on a Reference to return its `base value`
   - Searching the spec for "GetValue(", you will see that it *only* happens after evaluating an `Expression` of some kind
   - "Evaluating an `Expression`" means seeing what `Reference` an `Expression` returns
   - From this we can conclude that `Expressions` always evaluate to a `Reference` (a value)
   - Note: An `Expression` includes a wide range of other productions, such as `IdentifierReference`, which is deeply nested under the [Expression production](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-comma-operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An environment record is a [record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_(computer_science)) containing *multiple* variables.

A reference is an object representing something mutable, like an object's property or a *single* variable.

To find a value, like in `console.log(value)`, you could just look up the name "value" in the current lexical environment and have the identifier evaluate to that. But to assign a value, like in `value = 5`, you need the identifier to evaluate to something that represents the location where the number can be stored - and that's the `Reference` type. It contains a base - the record (of the lexical environment) - and an identifier - the name of the particular variable. It can either be dereferenced to the value ([`GetValue`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-getvalue)), or you can assign a new value to it ([`PutValue`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-putvalue)).

Comment: Just interested: In which case is the base value of a Reference undefined?

Comment: @JonasW. `undefined.property`, probably?

Comment: and `GetValue` will fail then?

Comment: @JonasW.Yes, exactly

Comment: Thanks Bergi. If the Environment Record is used to identify the actual variable / function that an Identifier is bound to, does that mean that each entry in an Environment Record is in fact a Reference? Additionally: If we are able to look up the value of an Identifier using an Environment Record, should we not be able to assign to it as well?

Comment: @JonasW. Wait, no, `undefined.property` throws before it can evaluate to a reference ([property accessors](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation) use `RequireObjectCoercible`). [`undefined` base values are used for unresolvable references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29353344/1048572) (or so I said), i.e. when you reference an undeclared variable

Comment: @Magnus No, the record is the storage itself (contains the memory for each variable). You can make a reference *to* it, but it is not a reference (to elsewhere) itself.

Comment: @Magnus Yes, we probably could do, but that means that for `Identifier = …` and `SomeOtherLeftHandSideExpression = …` you would need different evaluation rules in the assignment expression. And this really gets into a hassle when considering property assignments, like `superComplicated[Expression](withCall).property = …`. So it was simplified by saying that each left hand side expression evaluates to a *reference*, and then we *put* the righthandside value at the referenced location. It's all about abstraction in the spec.

Comment: Is it correct then, that Reference is only used in assignments, and in all other cases where we want to look up an Identifier, we just follow the lexical environment chain?

Comment: A reference is still needed for reading a variable too, because the "base" is used. For example: `var obj = { foo: function(){ console.log(this === obj); } }; with(obj) foo();` logs `true`.

Comment: @Magnus When evaluating an expression, you don't know whether it will be the target of an assignment or not - so you just always evaluate it to a reference. Then when it was an assignment target, `PutValue` is used, but otherwise if you just want the value `GetValue` is used.

Comment: @Magnus Notice that "following the lexical environment chain" (scope lookup) happens *before* the reference is created - it starts when evaluating an identifier in the current lexical environment. The reference will then point to a particular name in a particular record (which might be higher up in scope, not the record of the current environment).

Comment: @Magnus Also I lied when I said that assignments are the reason to use references - they are not the *only* reason. The Reference mechanisms are also used for the `typeof` and `delete` operators as well as for method calls.

Comment: Ahhh, I see that ResolveBinding (8.3.2) returns GetIdentifierReference (8.1.2.1), which actually always returns a Reference whose base value is the entire Environment Record that has a binding with the given Identifier (name) we were trying to resolve for. In other words, it always packages the result (the Environment Record) into a Reference type, then returns that. Did I get that right?

Comment: @Magnus The record *and the name*, yes.