# Deleting an object from a array in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to remove an object from the cart using its art_id, but when I'm getting this error `SyntaxError: Delete of an unqualified identifier in strict mode.` Why is this happening and how can I modify my code to come over this error

```
 function remove_from_cart(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.session);
        var art_id = req.params._id;

        var art_to_remove = _.findWhere(req.session.cart, {
            art_id: art_id
        });

        console.log(art_to_remove);
        delete art_to_remove;
        console.log(req.session);
        res.send('deleted')
    }
```

Comment: What do the first and second `console.log()` show?  It sounds like it's not finding the object you want to delete.

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643587/motive-behind-strict-mode-syntax-error-when-deleting-an-unqualified-identifier

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is delete not allowed in Javascript5 strict mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652589/why-is-delete-not-allowed-in-javascript5-strict-mode)

Comment: @Archer req.session contains an array of cart, the cart is supposed to have some objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it seems you're using `underscore`, you can use [`_.reject()`](http://underscorejs.org/#reject):

```
req.session.cart = _.reject(req.session.cart, { art_id: art_id });
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting this error SyntaxError: Delete of an unqualified
>   identifier in strict mode.

As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-delete-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

> When a delete operator occurs within strict mode code, a SyntaxError
>   exception is thrown if its UnaryExpression is a direct reference to a
>   variable, function argument, or function name

You need to use splice to delete values in array **rather than deleting a variable** (not allowed) which are pointing to filtered values.

Or **using underscore**, you can get the index of the fetched value using _findWhere as well

```
var b = _.indexOf(req.session.cart, art_to_remove );
req.session.cart.splice(b,1);
```

**A simple JS implemention** of the same could be

```
   req.session.cart = req.session.cart.filter(function(cart){
     return cart.art_id != art_id;
   })
```

Comment: Here `cart` is an array and deleting item from an array should be possible right(although not the correct way)? `art_to_remove` is neither *direct reference to a variable, function argument, or function name*

Comment: @sabithpocker `art_to_remove` is a variable.

Comment: But that is a reference to an object which is an array element, which qualifies to be deleted in strict mode. See [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12025291/427146) on why this is made as a `Syntax Error` instead of a `Type Error`.

Comment: @sabithpocker It is still a variable. Variables don't get deleted. Apart from reference value, they have reference name as well. Simply try this `var a = {}; delete a;` it will output `false` since it is not an allowed operation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Delete you have to use [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) so your code should look like this:

```
 function remove_from_cart(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session);
    var art_id = req.params._id;

    var art_to_remove = _.findWhere(req.session.cart, {
        art_id: art_id
    });

    console.log(art_to_remove);
    req.session.cart.splice(req.session.cart.indexOf(art_to_remove), 1);
    console.log(req.session);
    res.send('deleted')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example works:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var foo = [{x:1}, {y:2}, {z:3}];
  alert(delete foo[0]);
}());
```

While the below one doesn't:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var foo = [{x:1}, {y:2}, {z:3}];
  var y = foo[0];
  delete y;
}());
```

So for `delete` in `strict` mode you should probably use a syntax like `array[index]` or `object[property]` or `object.property`. A variable referring to the same doesn't work.

Also, `delete` on an array is not recommended as it doesn't update the `length` of the array and leads to holes in array. Its always better to use `splice`.

Answer (score 0):

i am expecting that req.session.cart is an array object which is not empty and req.params._id is not empty

```
function remove_from_cart(req, res, next) {
    var cart = req.session.cart;
    var art_id = req.params._id;

    var pos = cart.map(function(x) {return x.id; }).indexOf(art_id);
    var art_to_remove = cart[pos];
    cart.splice(pos, 1);

    console.log(art_to_remove);
    console.log(cart);

    res.send('deleted')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't directly delete object from an array.Have a look at this answer..
[How do I remove an object from an array with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396088/how-do-i-remove-an-object-from-an-array-with-javascript)